# mouseover shows raw html data and trigger infinite time

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I have a tree structure where on hover of the user image it should show some of other user related info but instead of show that info in proper div, its show raw HTML data.

**HTML Code**

there can be n number of `a href`

```
<a href="{{ route('user-binary-tree',[ 'eUserID' => $ERight12]) }}" class="bt-element binary-tree-on-hover" id="{{$ERight12}}">
                                    <img class="rounded-circle" style="width: 50px" src="{{ asset($packageImg) }}">
                                    {{ $Right12[0]->sponsor_code }}
                                </a>
```

**JavaScript code**

```
$('.binary-tree-on-hover').mouseover(function() {
        var userId = this.id;
        var $this = $(this);
        $.ajax('/binary-tree-ajax/' + userId + '/html', {
            method: "GET",
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(data) {
                $this.attr('title', data).mouseover(); //HTML DATA SHOW IN HOVER
            }
        });
    });
```

**Ajax response is**

```
<div class="bt-details">
<table class="table color-table inverse-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td class="text-center" style="font-size: 100%">Chethan k Test</td>
            <td class="text-center" style="font-size: 100%"></td>
            <td class="text-center">
                 <span class="btn btn-danger btn-xs btn-outline" style="border-width: 2px;">Inactive</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="text-center" style="font-size: 100%">Sponsor ID</td>
            <td class="text-center" style="font-size: 100%" colspan="2">UNO187175</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="text-center" style="font-size: 100%">Binary Qualified</td>
            <td class="text-center" style="font-size: 100%" colspan="2">
                <span class="btn btn-danger btn-xs btn-outline" style="border-width: 2px;">No</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th width="40%" class="text-center">Position</th>
            <td class="text-center" style="font-size: 95%">Left</td>
            <td class="text-center" style="font-size: 95%">Right</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th width="40%" class="text-center">Downline</th>
            <td class="text-center">39</td>
            <td class="text-center">6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th width="40%" class="text-center">Business</th>
            <td class="text-center">$0</td>
            <td class="text-center">$0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th width="40%" class="text-center">Carry</th>
            <td class="text-center">$0</td>
            <td class="text-center">$0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th width="40%" class="text-center" rowspan="2">Binary Generated</th>
            <td class="text-center" style="font-size: 95%">Last Day</td>
            <td class="text-center" style="font-size: 95%">Till Date</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="text-center">$0</td>
            <td class="text-center">$</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

When i hover on any of the user image its shows row HTML data instead of proper div as seen in 1st image
Also its keep calling the Ajax request infinite times but when i remove `$this.attr('title', data).mouseover();` its called Ajax request only once. so i think the infinite calling happening because of this line only.

**here how its shows**

[image]

**but i want to show like this**

[image]

Note : 2nd one is working but its not ajax call and it will fetch all the user info from controller and load on view hence when user increase it will slow down the page so i am trying to call ajax on hover of the image.

Comment: instead of title try to use bootstrap tooltip it has option to use HTML inside the tooltip https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/tooltips/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

End up with using popover function

**HTML Code**

```
<div id="popover_html" style="display:none;">
    hover_data
</div>
```

**JavaScript Code**

```
jQuery('.binary-tree-on-hover').popover({
    title: popoverContent,
    html: true,
    placement: 'bottom',
    trigger: 'hover'
});

function popoverContent() {
    var content = '';
    var element = $(this);
    var id = element.attr("id");
    var APP_URL = "{{ url('/')}}";
    const adminRoutePrefix = $("#admin_route_prefix").text();
    $.ajax({
        url: APP_URL + '/' + adminRoutePrefix + '/networks/binary-tree-ajax/' + id + '/html',
        method: "GET",
        async: false,
        // dataType: "HTML",
        success: function(data) {
             content = $("#popover_html").html();
             content = content.replace(/hover_data/g, data);
        }
    });

    return content;
}
```

Comment: With latest jQuery async: false, giving error `Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user’s experience. For more help http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/` but same code will work for earlier version of jQuery. Also if i change the value to `async: true,`, its not working for any jQuery version . Any suggestion ?